# Maven/Gradle support in IntelliJ Plugin

Tags: maven, gradle, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

I'm writing a plugin using IntelliJ SDK via the [gradle-intellij-plugin](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin).

I was able to add the dependencies so far, but now that I'm trying to add Maven/Gradle dependencies they are not seen.
[image]

I also added the jars of the IntelliJ plugins into the SDK classpath

[image]

Any idea of the reason? How can I introduce support for these Maven/Gradle thingy?

Answer (score 0):

The approach that you are shown is for those that are not using the gradle plugin to build new plugins.

According to the plugin [`README`](https://github.com/JetBrains/gradle-intellij-plugin/blob/master/README.md#setup-dsl) and to the IDE structure, these two are bundled plugins and must be imported using the folder name inside the plugins folder in the IntelliJ installation.

Just add

```
intellij {
    version = 'IntelliJVersion'
    pluginName = 'MyPluginName'

    plugins 'Maven', 'gradle'
}
```

in the `build.gradle`.

Pay attention to the case.

Comment: This resolves the depends in red, but I cannot still import the classes

Comment: @mat_boy I have no idea, maybe you need to import in the classpath some dependency. Anyway I think that I answered your question. Didn't I?